# What is the appropriate course of action an user should take in case a duplicated question is vandalized?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, specific-question

This discussion is with reference to the question [Remove this please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772599/remove-this-please), where the initial version of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54772599/1) was marked as *duplicate*.

Since the question was marked duplicate OP made a couple of changes and finally vandalized the question.

So would flagging be the appropriate action when we come across duplicated questions those are vandalized? If so how should these cases be categorized as:

- *spam*
- *rude or abusive*
- *in need of moderator intervention*

Comment: I just rolled it back. If the user persists in vandalizing, *then* raise a flag.

Comment: Just roll it back. If the OP keeps vandalizing, flag for moderator attention. But I believe that if you roll it back several times, an auto-flag will be raised.

Comment: I would avoid a roll back war. Rollback the first time and then flag for moderator if OP persists

Comment: This is all kinda silly beacuse there is nothing stopping the user deleting the question. No answers, no votes. It's simply a case of they not knowing how to use the site.

Comment: @yivi, By the same token, the user probably isn't aware that good duplicates are *encouraged* as they help others. Not saying that's the case here, but if someone thinks there are distinct keywords missing from the target, then the closed Q&A may be a net gain for SO and it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: It took the user only 4 minutes to follow yivi's advice, that's the proper and low-friction way.

Comment: @jpp You can vote to undelete later on if you really, really want. But the user has the right to delete their own post. Or repost the question and vote to close as duplicate if you really, really think "it's a net gain". But no need to be user-hostile for something as silly as a dupe with no answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just handle it like any vandalism:

- Rollback the edit
- If there's a pattern of vandalism (user vandalizing multiple questions, e.g. an attempt to remove all his content from the site), modflag
- Monitor to see if the user vandalizes the question again, if so, modflag
- Consider posting a comment explaining that vandalism is not acceptable, the CC BY SA license and the possibility of deleting the question if possible

Don't flag vandalized posts as rude/abusive/spam unless that's appropriate for another reason (the author edits in rude content/spam).